# Nested Hover in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am creating the test cases for my learning using Selenium C# in Orange Hrm application.
https://enterprise-demo.orangehrmlive.com/auth/login
Username and password: admin.

Once I login, there are differen menu, I am traversing through Admin>User Management>users and click on Users.
However, I am not getting way to how to use the MouseOver in Selenium C#.
Attached is the screenshot for your reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkOur.png)

Answer (score 1):

From my limited knowledge you'll have to do it in a few steps.
Below is an example using NgWebDriver (angularJS app)

```
            Actions builder = new Actions(ngDriver);
            var elementToHover= ngDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("dpcontract"));
            builder.MoveToElement(elementToHover, 10 , 0)
            builder.Build().Perform();
```

This builds a new action by finding the target element, moving the mouse to its position (x/y) with a 10 offset on the x (in my case).

You can add more events to that action trigger. The original (working) code for a drag and drop type-action i have is this

```
            Actions builder = new Actions(ngDriver);
            var elementToClick = ngDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("dpcontract"));

            builder.MoveToElement(elementToClick, elementToClick.Size.Width - 1, 0)
            .ClickAndHold()
            .MoveByOffset(150, 0)
            .Release();

            builder.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: You are certainly right, however I am not using the ngdriver. Based on your suggestions, I have modified and wrote which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jens Stragier for your suggestion. Based on your suggestion, I wrote as follows and it worked for me.

```
            Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
            action.MoveToElement(elemWomen);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            action.ClickAndHold(elemWomen);
            action.Release(TShirt);
           action.Click(TShirt);
            action.Perform();
```

Comment: If you are performing ClickAndHold in Chrome, you may have to add a MoveByOffset(1,1) as a workaround.